# How to integrate Angular 9 with a camunda modeler?

Tags: camunda-modeler, bpmn.io, bpmn-js

I searched for ways to get the camunda modeler into angular 9 application. What I found was using `bpmn-js` library and its other dependencies like `bpmn-js-properties-panel`, etc.

I was able to get the following output:

[image]

But, as in the online camunda modeler, I cannot see the connectors in my implementation. I know that there is a dependency called `bpmn-js-connectors-extension` but that is not working and I got below errors.

*ERROR in ./node_modules/bpmn-js-connectors-extension/dist/index.es.js 775:11-16
export 'isAny' was not found in 'bpmn-js/lib/util/ModelUtil'
ERROR in ./node_modules/bpmn-js-connectors-extension/dist/index.es.js 977:11-16
export 'isAny' was not found in 'bpmn-js/lib/util/ModelUtil'*

The dependencies that I'm using are below.

- "bpmn-js": "6.3.4",
- "bpmn-js-connectors-extension": "^0.4.6",
- "bpmn-js-properties-panel": "0.37.5",
- "camunda-bpmn-moddle": "^7.0.1",
- "core-js": "3.6.4",
- "diagram-js": "^11.13.0"

I need to know whether there is any way to integrate camunda modeler into Angular 9 and if using `bpmn-js` is okay, then what is the way to get the camunda connectors as below?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The question was answered in the bpmn-js forum https://forum.bpmn.io/t/bpmn-js-connector-extension/9276

The connectors extension is deprecated. You can use
[GitHub - bpmn-io/bpmn-js-create-append-anything: A create/append anything bpmn-js extension](https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-js-create-append-anything) instead.

Try and update your dependencies, too. bpmn-js v6 is 3 years old.